# How to interpret metric spring.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.offset from Actuator for Spring Cloud Stream Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-actuator

I am exposing Kafka offset metric through Spring Boot Actuator. When I use the curl command:

```
    http://server/actuator/metrics/spring.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.offset
```

I get the following:

```
    {"name":"spring.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.offset",
     "description":"Consumer lag for a particular group and topic",
     "baseUnit":"seconds",
     "measurements":[{"statistic":"VALUE","value":0.152}],
     "availableTags":[{"tag":"topic","values":["kafka.topic.input"]}, 
                      {"tag":"group","values":["Consumer1"]}]
     }
```

What does the measurement of 0.152 seconds mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug, [fixed in 2.1](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/commit/3b4bff959fca55be257c33e04cfb1b0214a92674).

A `TimeGauge` (scaled to milliseconds) was used instead of a simple `Gauge`.

So, it appears the number means your total lag across all partitions was 152.

Comment: Thanks Gary. From the link you posted I saw this comment "Kafka Offset just numerical value not Time". Does it mean there are 152 pending messages to be processed by my consumers across all patitions?

Comment: It appears so, yes.